# Creating an in-memory storage using Akka actors

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Akka using a pet project. This is basically a tournament-style server, having a pool of players. On each round, it should fetch two random players from the pool, play them against each other, then update a scoreboard. The whole thing sits behind an HTTP server. Players are added via an HTTP Post message, and games are triggered via a 'Play' message that's to be sent from a JS client.

The way I thought of implementing it is as follows:

- a PlayerPool actor handling two messages, 'AddPlayer' and 'Play'
- a Round actor that takes a message with two players, plays a round, then updates the
- GameResults actor, containing a list of played rounds and the winner of each round. It also sports the 'GetScore' message which returns the scoreboard.
- The HTTP layer is a Spray Routing actor, exposing calls for 'GetScore', 'AddPlayer' and 'Play', talking to the PlayerPool and GameResults actors.

My problem is that two separate actors are talking to GameResults - both Spray directly, and the Round actor, and apparently two separate instances of GameResults are being created, so that while Round adds a result to one instance, Spray is reading the scoreboard from another instance. Obviously I'm missing something very basic and before attempting to resolve the issue, I'd like to understand what's the canonic way of doing this in Akka? basically this problem can be reduced to an actor that holds a state across different calls.

Would be glad to have someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: show some code, there is no need to init GameResults 2 times, it can be a single actor holding the results.

Comment: The same line of code in both actors: val gameResults: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[GameResults], "results")

Comment: is this called only once in the code ?

Comment: Twice. From two different actors.

Comment: so you are creating 2 different actors, you should init the actor only once, if you need to send a message to a specific actor from another actor use the actor ref

Comment: Where do I initialize it, then?

Comment: if you think the GameResults actor should be a top level actor dont init it inside another actor, do it outside somewhere in your app where you init the spray actors and all the other actors needed to work

Answer (score 1):

code snippet example how to pass messages from spray to your game result actor :

hope this helps

```
        object SomeApp extends App{

        //create a actor system
          val yourSystem = ActorSystem("Your-System")

          //init spray actor
          val restHandler = yourSystem.actorOf(Props[RestHandler], name = "Rest-spray")

          //init play pool actor
          val playerPoolActor = yourSystem.actorOf(Props[PlayerPool], name = "playerPool")

          //INIT ONLY 1 game result actor
          val gameResultsActor  = yourSystem.actorOf(Props[GameResults], name = "gameResults")

          //spray listen to all IP on port 90210
          IO(Http)(yourSystem) ! Http.Bind(restHandler, interface = "0.0.0.0" , port = 90210)

          class RestHandler extends Actor with RestHandlerRoute  {
            def actorRefFactory = context
            //nice to hold the route in a diffrent trait
            def receive = runRoute(someRoute)
          }
        }

        //only thing the trait is doing is configuring the routing and send message to relavant actor
        trait RestHandlerRoute extends HttpService{me: Actor =>
          import SomeApp._

          val someRoute =
            path("getGameResults")  { get { respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { complete {
                //case the user requested http://someIP:90210/getGameResults spray will send a message to the game result actor
                gameResultsActor ! getResult
            } ~
        }
```

Comment: I don't really get how you pass the GameResults actor reference from SomeApp to RestHandlerRoute (do you do that?). Also how will I pass the reference to the Round actor (which then needs to send results to GameResults)?

Comment: import SomeApp._ gives me access to the objects members. 1 of them is a actor ref called gameResultActor

Comment: That doesn't really seem to me to be the canonical way to do this sort of thing in Akka. But I might be wrong...

Comment: this is just a example how to send a message to an actor using spray. if you find the canonical way that suites you. please share.